# Given series is convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln(n))^2}$$

I thought I can compare it with $\frac{1}{n}$ but I couldn't prove it (and be satisfied with it). Therefore, how should I approach these type of series ? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln^2 n}{n}
 = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2 \ln n \cdot (1/n)}{1}
 = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2\ln n}{n}
 = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2/n}{1}
 = 0
$$
by using L'Hospital's rule twice. Hence, for large $n$, $\ln^2 n < n$ and now use comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

For the series, you can use the *integral test*: since for $n\ge 2$, $\;x\ln x>\ln^2 x>0$, the improper integral
$$\int _2^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{\ln^2x}\ge\int _2^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{x\ln x}=\ln (\ln x)\biggm |_2^{+\infty}=+\infty $$
diverges.

*Added*: This series is a  particular case of the *Bertrand's series:
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1{n^\alpha \ln^\beta n},$$
which are known to converge if and only if $\;(\alpha >1)$ or $(\alpha =1$ *and* $\beta >1)$.